# Nagelkerke pseudo-R2 with positive log likelihoods

Tags: mixed-model, maximum-likelihood

I'm trying to calculate a pseudo-R2 for linear mixed models using Nagelkerke's method .

My understanding is that Nagelkerke's pseudo-R2=1-EXP[(-2/n)(l(B)-l(0))], where l(B) and l(0) are the maximized log-likelihoods for the fitted model of interest and the null (intercept only) model, respectively.

The pseudo-R2 is then rescaled to a maximum of 1 by dividing by R2(max), where R2(max)=1-EXP[(2/n)*l(0)].

My problem is that in some cases the log-likelihood for the model of interest (and sometimes also the null model) is positive. Consequently, R2>R2(max), leading to rescaled R2 values that are either negative or >1. Am I doing something wrong here? If not, is there a different method for calculating reasonable pseudo-R2 for models with positive log likelihoods?

Thank you, in advance, for any advice.

Laura Perry

Comment: Do you have continuous or discrete densities? If continuous the log likihoods *can* be > 1; however in practice with data points away from mode / mean I would be very surprised to see this .  Lastly if this is on a test dataset, rather than train, then it is entirely possible to have negative pseudo r2 -> your model is worse than baseline (overfitting).